# Onsen UI: how to set value initial-index for carousel

Tags: onsen-ui

After I called carousel page from menu, I want to display a specified carousel item.
I tried to use method like that

```
myCarsouselContent.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(index);
```

The problem is, carousel will slide step by step until `index.`
I don't want to show slide in screen. I think the best way is set value for `initial-index = index`. But I don't know how to do this.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed my answer since there is an `initial-index` attribute which is better. Sorry about that.

Use `initial-index="2"` (or whatever index you like) as an attribute for `<ons-carousel>`.

```
<ons-carousel initial-index="2">
  ...
</ons-carousel>
```

Here you can see it in action:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/MYaGLK

Comment: Thank you, Andreas.
However, screen seem be lagged. When I tested in Iphone 4 or Android device, it take a little of time.
do you have any idea else?

Comment: I changed my answer. You should use `initial-index` instead of `setActiveCarouselItemIndex()`.